# How To Replace \n or \" in CString With appropriate code values so as ensure that JSON parsing is succesfull MFC?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

i Have CString str. for example contains this string:
str = "hi there how are you.
add me as your "friend"";

if you observe, you have \n and \" included in cstring. Json Parsing is not successful because of that \n and \". how do i replace them. also it should be language independent. please help.

Comment: Are you writing a JSON encoder? If not, why are you not using a JSON encoder?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the grammar is c/c++-like, so `"\n"` and `"\""`.  Hence, in C++, the code would be `"\\n"` and `"\\\""`.

Check out http://www.json.org/